# Rotating moving bitmaps in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

I'm trying to build a simple "flappy bird" game, I need for the image of the bird to tilt, pointing upwards when going up and vice-versa. However, when rotating my image, it partially or completely disappears from the screen after falling a little or after I tap the screen. Can someone please tell me how to fix this problem?

```
        matrix = new Matrix();
        if(angle > minAngle && angle < maxAngle && !boosting) {
            angle+=avel;
            matrix.postRotate(angle);
        }
        if(boosting) {
            angle = -20;
            matrix.postRotate(angle);
            speed = -30;
        }
        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 50, 50, matrix, true);
        bitmap = rotatedBitmap;
        //Now the player object gets this rotated image and adds it to the Canvas
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap rotation(Bitmap myBitmap) {

    int rotate = 90; // degree of rotation;


            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotate);
            if (myBitmap != null) {
                return   myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(),
                        myBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            }

    return myBitmap;
}
```